# Lucene merge stop resume

Tags: merge, lucene, resume

Our product requires real time Lucene index merge in an embeded device. The device may get shutdown anytime. My team is exploring posibility of resume merge after system reboot. In our POC, all consumers from SegmentMerger are overrided by customized codec and the whole merge process is divided into many fine-grain steps. When each step is done, its state is saved in disk to avoid redo after resume. From test, this can work. However, I am not able to determine how robust this solution can be or it is built on flawed foundation.

Thanks in advance for your response

Comment: so, since you write this one - you could try it and check if it's robust, right?

Comment: yeah good point. can you share your results